# jQuery Post Method Results Success With 500 Server Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I use this code:

```
$.post('contact.php', {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    message: $('#message').val()
}, function(data) {
    if (data == 'Message sent!') {
        alert('Success') ;
    }
});
```

PHP file returns "Message sent!", but with 500 Internal Server Error.
How can I accomplish this problem?
Thanx!

Comment: look in error.log from your apache? and post the error

Comment: 500 internal server error means there's problem with server code, display/log error and you'll know what need to be corrected

Answer (score 1):

It is because after echoing 'Message Sent' your php files looks for something which is not found on server like `favicon.ico` or any other file might be `js` or `css`. So to remove this use `exit;` after `echoing` like,

```
 echo 'Message Sent!';
 exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Internal Server Error messages indicate that something in general is wrong.

Most of the time, "wrong" means an issue with the page or site's programming but there's certainly a chance the problem is on users end.  [source](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm)
 Second echo from your php code a json success and validate in your js

**PHP**

```
if($some_var){
 echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
}
else{
 echo json_encode(array('error'=>$error_nsg));
}
```

**JS**

```
if(data.success){
console.log("success msg");
}
elseif (data.error){
console.log("error msg");
}
```